# Django Rest API- use prefetch_related with ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a comment field for every blog post. **I want to pass Comment.objects.all() from Views.py to ModelSerializer def get_comments(self, obj)** to reduce the number of sql queries. As I am serializing a list of blog posts

**Views.py**

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().annotate(
        author_name=F('author__username')
    )
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

        def list(self, request):
            return Response({'blogs': BlogSerializer(self.queryset, many=True).data})
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class BlogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    comments = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title_text', 'main_text', 'datepublished', 'author_name', 'id', 'comments')


    def get_comments(self, obj):
        # filter comment
        comment_object = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id)
        comments = CommentSerializer(comment_object, many=True).data
        return comments
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to pass anything from the View.

- First, you have to change the `comments` field in your `BlogSerializer`.

```py
class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # This serializer should have all the details of your comments.
    ....
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = "__all__" # Or whatever fields you want to set.

class BlogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # I am not sure of the source of your comment reverse manager name

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title_text', 'main_text', 'datepublished', 'author_name', 'id', 'comments')
```

- Second, you have to make a small change to your view's queryset in order to reduce the number of queries sent to the database by using [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```py
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.prefetch_related('comments').all().annotate(
        author_name=F('author__username')
    )
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

        def list(self, request):
            return Response({'blogs': BlogSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True).data})
```

> I assumed in the code snippets that you didn't set a `related_name` on your `Blog` `ForeignKey` for the `Comment` model, so by default, its related manager on `Blog` will be `comment_set`

## Update

Your models should look like this, in order for this solution to work

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    ...

class Blog(models.Model):
    # comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 
    # this foreign key shouldn't be here, remove it.

    ....
```

#### Do the changes on Serializer and View

```py
# in BlogSerializer
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
# In BlogViewSet
    queryset = Blog.objects.prefetch_related('comments').all().annotate(
        author_name=F('author__username')
    )
```

Comment: I added a model comment to the ForeignKey of the post without verbose_name and did everything as you wrote. But an error comes out "Cannot find 'comment_set' on Blog object, 'comment_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()"

Comment: can you post your `models.py` file, in order to see how your models are related.

Comment: [models.py](https://github.com/eggRT/example/blob/main/models.py)

Comment: a quick note here, your foreign key in Blog model, this means that your blog post will have only 1 comment, is that how you want your blog post to be?

Comment: Check the Update section in my answer, It will work after these changes

Comment: Wow it works). my comment models were the same, I changed them later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great to hear that

Comment: what those F do and from where it imported